# Can a Dementor kiss a muggle (or squib)?

Tags: harry-potter, dementors

I've searched both google and the site but looks like this hasn't been asked yet.

The closest Dementors have come to attacking a muggle is the attack on Harry and Dudley in the beginning of OotP.

Dementors seem to attack both Harry and Dudley, but I'm not sure the soul sucking of muggles has ever been mentioned.

Muggles can definitely sense them even though they can't see Dementors.

Could a Dementor suck the soul out of a muggle (and/or a squib)? What would the result look like to muggles? After an Avada Kedavra the muggles can at least tell the victim is dead. What would a soul-sucked muggle look like to other muggles?

Comment: I think a kissed muggle looks like a person in a mental hospital that is unaware of their surroundings

Comment: @atayenel precisely. Unable to speak or act, with only life support functioning. I do not remember if in Book 6 they mentioned Dementor victims found by the muggles. But the quote from Book 5 is definite proof

Comment: No mention of Dementor-kissed muggles where I suggested, so no canon evidence whatsoever

Comment: posts should really only contain one question per post. I count three here

Comment: @NKCampbell I agree. And the second part has no canon answers

Comment: Of course not. Muggles don't leave ghosts, so they obviously don't have souls. Since a Dementor's kiss eats your soul, doing the procedure on a muggle would be pointless :P ... unless you actually believe that Avada Kedavra actually strikes at the soul and does no other damage - in that case, it is at least *some* evidence that Muggles have something at least resembling a soul in some respects, since we see Muggles killed by the Killing Curse.

Comment: @Luaan according to Dumbledore in book 7, leaving a ghost is a conscious choice made by a dying wizard. Muggles cannot become ghosts, but that does not imply they don't have a soul. And quote from the book in my answer directly states that a Dementor was about to steal a soul from a Muggle (Dudley). I discount the possibility of a Dementor being stupid and trying to steal a soul where there is none. 

Actually, it is a separate question: do Muggles have a soul.

Comment: @timsparrow follow up question: then do squibs have soul? What about muggle (or magic, for that matter) animals? Do inferi have souls?

Comment: @user13267 If you have a follow up question you should ask it separately. Although I would assume they have souls.

Answer (score 37):

## Yes, they can.

In Book 5, stray Dementors

> Sent by Dolores Umbridge

attempted to kiss not only Harry, but Dudley Dursley as well.

<sub>From Chapter 1, Dudley Demented</sub>

> He had run barely a dozen steps when he reached them: Dudley was curled on the ground, his arms clamped over his face; a second dementor was crouching low over him, gripping his wrists in its slimy hands, prizing them slowly, almost lovingly apart, lowering its hooded head toward Dudley’s face as
> though about to kiss him. ...

## Concerning the second part of the question:

As there is no case of a Muggle being kissed by a Dementor, we can only speculate. [As all human beings, wizard and muggle alike, have a soul in H.P](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/188748/do-muggles-squibs-or-inferi-have-souls-just-like-wizards)., most likely, they will enter a coma-like state. Will they die? Possibly.

So, in addition to dead people with no obvious cause of death (A.K.), muggle will observe comatose people with no obvious cause, or disease.

Comment: What about the second part if the question?

Comment: @user13267, added, but pure speculation.

Comment: Lupin states that someone who's been kissed will not die but live on without their soul since the body can survive without the soul.

Comment: @TheDarkLord If you add the source you can make it an answer